# Keep the changes of a web page after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I recently developed a script to highlight text in a web page based on `document.execCommand()` but the changes are gone if I refresh my web page.

How can I keep the change for every user ?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to persist after a refresh?

Comment: i would like to keep the highlited text with the document.execCommand() function. i cant use server side so it will be client side. thank you again.

Comment: Hope this discucssion help someone with the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am rather unsure what you actually want to persist I will give some generic information.

Some good reading at [DiveIntoHtml5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) on storage.

I would suggest taking a look at either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` now while these are regarded generally as `HTML5` the browser support is much greater.

You can see the support of `keyValueStorage` at [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage)

You can store a key / value pair as follows:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

You can then retrieve the value as follows:

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Remove:

```
localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

`sessionStorage` works the same as above but will only persist while the browser is open. It persists for the "session" of the browser. However `localStorage` will persist until it is removed by code or by clearing the browser.

Comment: thank you i'm going to dive in to the subject of the local storage

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to save state.

One is to write client-side code that passes information back to the server for storage.

The other is to save what is called a cookie on the client computer. Normally JavaScript is not allowed to read or write files on the client-computer (an important security feature), but it can generate data strings that the Web browser can store in a special file commonly referred to as a cookie jar. The cookie jar is a configuration file, a file that provides information on how to set up the browser.

Remember that no cookie can be larger than 4KB.

Comment: Please don't suggest cookies! Can't we get past this already!

Comment: You are right, but i still have to deal with ie 7, so cookie is a good alternative.

Comment: But you would be better off using a simple Polyfill for IE7 support. At least then only IE7 is actually going to be using cookies.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know about Polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a good guide on [state management for web applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647327.aspx). Check it out and you'll see all the options that would come in question for you. Then pick whatever seems best fit.
Once you know what you want, you can search stack overflow for a concrete implementation of your problem. There's bound to already be an answer.

Edit: Table 5.5: "State Management Mechanisms for Web Applications" is the one you want to look at for an overview.